# I want to call a method after particular time until my app opened in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to call a method after each 2 minutes, 
how can I apply such logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)..

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourFunction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
.........
..........

-(void)yourFunction:(NSTimer*)timer{
//do your action here
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but the time interval is in seconds - it should be 120.0, not 2.0.

Comment: sorry, he asked 2 minutes..gosh..I read it as 2 seconds...Edited..thanks Sherm Pendley...

Answer (score 4):

Use an NSTimer object. It's been talked about quite a lot here, so I won't repeat all that - just search for "NSTimer" in the search box at the top right. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use a `NSTimer` to trigger a method. I use the below code in my initial `viewDidLoad` section:

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120.0 target:self selector:@selector(theMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Hope that helps.